# IPinFlowControl of Infinite Pin Tee Filter

Tags: visual-c++, directshow

i want to Block output from one of pins of `Infinite Pin Tee filter`,

so i tried to get `IPinFlowControl` of one of output pin, but i am getting `E_Pointer` in HResult.

Below is my code

```
IPin *pOutInfiniteTee2=NULL;

hr = FindUnconnectedPin(infiniteTeeFilter,PINDIR_OUTPUT,&pOutInfiniteTee2);

//ConnectFilter..using..pOutInfiniteTee2

IPinFlowControl *ipinFlow=NULL;
    hr=pOutInfiniteTee2->QueryInterface(IID_IPinFlowControl,(void **)&ipinFlow);
```

how to use IPinFlowControl with InfineTeePin fitler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As MSDN states, `IPinFlowControl` is not available on [Infinite Pin Tee Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849413/ipinflowcontrol-of-infinite-pin-tee-filter):

```
Filter Interfaces   IBaseFilter
Input Pin Media Types   Any media type
Input Pin Interfaces    IMemInputPin, IPin, IQualityControl
Output Pin Media Types  Any media type. The output type always matches the input type, for all output pins
Output Pin Interfaces   IMediaPosition, IMediaSeeking, IPin, IQualityControl
Filter CLSID    CLSID_InfTee
```

Comment: `IPinFlowControl` is a rare thing. Unless you implement it on your filter, you are unlikely to utilize it on another one. At the very least, you have to make sure with docs on the filter of interest, that this interface is available.